# Kubernetes monitoring using zabbix

Tags: kubernetes, zabbix

When I install zabbix proxy into kubernetes cluster, in proxy logs I see the error:

```json
 **ERROR: Request failed with status code 401: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}**
```

Hi there,
I'm facing an error while setting up Kubernetes cluster monitoring using zabbix.
I followed the guide here https://git.zabbix.com/projects/ZT/repos/kubernetes-helm/browse?at=release%2F6.4.
Zabbix is installed alongside with kuber. Its installed in another dedicated server and works in docker containers.
When I install zabbix proxy into kubernetes cluster, in proxy logs I see the error:

```json
 **ERROR: Request failed with status code 401: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}**
```

However, I obtained the token of service account which has been created for zabbix.
Cannot handle this issue. Tried several times to reinstall the helm chart and input new-generated token of zabbix SA.
What can be the reason?
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well I also got similar error, the reason for that is having "**%**" at the end of the token, please remove it and verify, It's working for me.